# loop until IP:port is responding

Tags: loops, powershell

I have a simple inquire but test-netConnection or test-connection are giving me a hard time while used in a loop.
So basically I want to run in a loop until a server is responding to my connection attempt on a certain port.
With test-connection I see that you cannot specify a port, so the solution I guess is to use tnc - test-netconnection.

In a do while loop it doesn't work as tnc doesn't use a continuous ping/connect attempts.

```
do {
  Write-Host "waiting..."
  sleep 3      
} until(Test-NetConnection $HOST -Port PORT)
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The code above doesn't work because the until test only verifies if the result is not null. `Test-NetConnection` always returns an object(even with false as a status), so the test would always be "true", which means that your `do { }` scriptblock would only run once no matter what the result is. One solution would be to make the until test check one of the properties returned, like this:

```
do {
  Write-Host "waiting..."
  sleep 3      
} until(Test-NetConnection $HOST -Port PORT | ? { $_.TcpTestSucceeded } )
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Frode!

I implemented that and it works as expected. In a script until the connection is established, tnc will return the warning messages until the port can be reached. 
I was able to overcome those messages with -WarningPreference SilentlyContinue, as the tnc param -InformationLevel will mess up wiuth the do until loop.

Comment: How would you add a timeout / attempt limit to this?

Comment: Great answer, many thanks. With regard to the output of `Test-NetConnection` - if you add the arguments `-InformationLevel Quiet` it will return true/false so that this works: `until(Test-NetConnection $HOST-Port $PORT -InformationLevel Quiet)`. I had to work this out as docker-compose didn't like the `$_` in my entrypoint override